# Climate: Calculate Consecutive Days of Rain

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data column rainfall, and a column is on that date;
I intend to extract Consecutive Days of Rain from it in a separate column.
With the formula below, I extracted Consecutive :

```
columnF=IF(B2>0,SUM(F1)+1,0)
```

But the result is in a column and I can not separate them like in attached picture (see desired result).
If we want to extract the continuity of rainfall in a separate column
How to do?

My result: 
[image]

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: Calculate two helper columns (hidden is ok). The 1st you have. The 2nd will have the max of the running total. So {0,2,2,0,2,2,0,3,3,3,0,4,4,4,4,0}. Somehow leverage the 1st helper column to derive the 2nd helper column. All the cells in the dx#day columns have the formula `=if(column() - column(dx1day) + 1 = 2nd-helper-column, 1st-helper-column, "")` Where the helper column address references are given with an absolute Column Letter and relative row number (which should be the same as the row of the formula). This way when the formula is copied, the row reference updates properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following from Ted D's comment... a possible formula for the second helper column would be (in cell `G2`):

```
=IF(F2=0,0,MATCH(0,F3:F999,0)-1+F2)
```

This looks for the first `0` in the counter column (`F`) beneath our row (looking around 1000 rows down - that `999` can be changed as appropriate). We use that plus our current counter to give us the size of the block.

From there, we can make the columns with the `dx1day` etc. titles and populate them with the formula:

```
=IF($G2=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(H$1,3,999),"day","")),$F2,"")
```

This is parsing the number from `dx1day` at the top of the column (in this case `H`) (if you did it with just numbers and a custom format you could save that bit*). We then check if the current "block size" value (in column `G`) is the same as that in the header. If it is we copy the counter value (from column `F`), otherwise blank.

You can get away from this second helper column by replacing the `$G2` with `(IF($F2=0,0,MATCH(0,$F3:$F999,0)-1+$F2))` - but if makes it a bit more of a headache to understand (and debug :-)

*the way for this is to do custom format with the "Type" being `"dx"0"day"`... then the formula becomes `=IF($G2=H$1,$F2,"")` or `=IF((IF($F2=0,0,MATCH(0,$F3:$F999,0)-1+$F2))=H$1,$F2,"")` for the no-second-helper-column version

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @alirezakarbalaee - if this works for you, please accept the answer